# vue-router change only one of the named view without affecting the others

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am testing with vue-router and come across this problem, what if i have two named views but i only want to change one of it without changing the default view. Currently I do it like this:

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      components: {
        default: Foo,
        change: Bar,
      }
    }
    {
      path: '/foo/test1',
      components: {
        default: Foo,
        change: test1,
      }
    }

    //is it possible to do it something like this?
    {
      path: '/:foo/test1',
      components: {
        default: :foo//<--- how to keep default to whatever it previously have?
        change: test1
      }
    }

  ]
})
```

```html
<router-view></router-view>
<router-view name="change"></router-view>
```

I think i can do this with dynamic matching, get the current route name and pass it as param, but I need to keep the current default route (like some form inputs), so i'd rather want to change only one of the views without affecting the others... please help...

Comment: This sort of thing is typically done with nested routes instead of named views.

Answer (score 0):

I took long to find someone with the same problem!

I believe you solved it already but I think there is no solution when the named ***router-view*** isn't to be used by current route children.

What I mean is, can't use in your Vue app a router in a ***router-view*** (named or not) without loosing the current rendered view in other route unless it is through defining it in children route.

What I've seen was by using the same component as parent component entry and has children components entry, in the same ***router-view*** it doesn't loose what was rendered by parent route. [https://dev.to/berniwittmann/handling-dialogs-with-vue-router-29ji]

What I did was removed it from the router, render it in the same place where the ***router-view*** was, unattached from any route, now is working as intended!

Hope it helps. (even after some years later)