# vue Only Load the component content upon request

Tags: webpack, vue.js, single-page-application, vue-router

i'm new to vue, I encountered this problem, say I have dozen popup that contains heavy contents that is actually only needed upon request. I realized my previous approach is wrong (I tried vue-router to render the content, but it was not effective since the content under the popup would change everytime i push to new route). [I tried named views, but I still think its wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47666624/vue-router-change-only-one-of-the-named-view-without-affecting-the-others?noredirect=1#comment82296347_47666624). Now my question is, how about I put it inside as a modal compoent? Will it only be rendered upon show? Or will it be rendered at once I attached it to the components regardless if its showing or not? How can I make it only render, say after a user click a button?

```
export default {
name: ‘app’,
components: {Modal1,Modal2,Modal3,Modal4}, <-- are all this will be rendered?
}
```

Btw, I'm using webpacks. Also, I'm new to SPA development so I'm not sure if i'm grasping the concept of rendering correctly... I just want to make sure the page would be rendered first and load without waiting for each modal to finish rendering... Also it must be accessible from any router-view inside the app.

EDIT: Upon further research, I think I can do it with dynamic components. I think i'm on the right track now, i just need help finding the right guide out ther.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi since you mentioned you are using webpack the right approach will be to make use of the "lazy load" & "code splitting" feature.
something specific to vue can be found [here](https://alexjoverm.github.io/2017/07/16/Lazy-load-in-Vue-using-Webpack-s-code-splitting/)